# Executing external executable to run and wait till it finishes and continue the setup using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am new to NSIS install creator and I need to run an external executable because this is an prerequisite and once it if finished i will be continuing the setup.
I tried the below code but it just copies the exe to the installation path.

```
    Section "example" example
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  MessageBox MB_OK \
    "The applications."
  File "Prerequisites\setup.exe"
  ExecWait '"exec" /i "$INSTDIR\setup.exe"  /passive'
  SetRebootFlag true
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

That would only work if there is a `exec.exe` in the path on the end users system, try `ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\setup.exe"  /passive'`